# How do I know when to read a number as (for example) 241 or 24.1 off the navigation computer?

Tags: navigation

How do I know in what way I should read a number off the naviagtion computer scale on the slide rule side?

Eg. 241 and 24.1

Comment: What do you mean by "navigation computer"? [An E6B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E6B), or something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about an E6B, you follow the same rules for your result as you followed for your inputs. If you used a factor of 10 for your inputs, you use a factor of 10 for your results. If all else fails, you use the common sense rule. For your particular calculations, does 241 make sense? Or, does 24.1 make sense?